# How do I sort a set of jQuery-objects (but not their position in the DOM/Markup)

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

We have following markup

```
<input type="checkbox" class="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="foo" />
<input type="checkbox" class="foo" />
```

At some point I inject a `data`-keyValuePair for each instance (each one is unique - i have several calls - example only covers one assignment) with jQuery like:

```
$('myMagicSelector').data('counter', '1');
```

Now I am trying to sort this instance with following code

```
var $checkboxes = $('.foo').filter('checked');
$checkboxes.sort(function (a, b) {
    var dataA = a.data('counter');
    var dataB = b.data('counter');

    return dataA < dataB;
});
```

I know ... this can't work ...

- How do I fix my code, without introducing neither `$(a)` nor `$(b)` in my sort-function?
- Is there any library which can do this for me (jquery-specific)?
- Any other inputs?

Very important note:
I do not want to change the ordering in my UI (nope: no UI-sort-thing... like [tinySort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/)), and the ordering in my UI does not correspond to the expected result - that's why I need to sort on the fly, and not via the markup at creation ...

Comment: You could use [tinysort](http://tinysort.sjeiti.com/) I think

Comment: @m90 as far as i understood, tinySort also changes the position in the DOM/markup ... but please see my "very important note" for this :)

Comment: Yes, but you could always clone your nodes into a helper object or something similar and perform your sorting there.

Comment: @m90 that would be an alternative - but ... performance? ... btw: please transform your comment into an answer...

Comment: @m90 `.clone()` won't work, as it does not clone one of my complex data-keyValuePairs (which i need later on)

Comment: How does this *complex* data actually look like?

Comment: @m90 a custom javascript-object like (basic example): `var foo = { 'a': '1', 'b': 'foo' }; $('selector').data('foo', foo);`

Comment: You'd have to use `.attr` instead of `.data` then: http://jsfiddle.net/zxLtD/

Comment: @m90 this would mean an immense change in my code - i would have to adapt all my readings/writings from/to/of my complex data-object... atm i'd rather attach my special sort-value as an attribute to my checkboxes and use the approach of RoryMcCrossan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `el.getAttribute("data-counter")` in place of `$(a).data("counter")`

```
var $checkboxes = $('.foo:checked');
$checkboxes.sort(function (a, b) {
    var dataA = a.getAttribute("data-counter");
    var dataB = b.getAttribute("data-counter");
    return dataA < dataB;
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/99kdn/)

Comment: what if i do not work with `data-`-attributes, but instead with `$().data('counter', '3')`?

Comment: I don't understand your comment, as your example is a data attribute?

Comment: If you mean you want to set the attribute, use `a.getAttribute("data-counter", 3);`

Comment: I don't see how your update would affect your sorting algorithm? The `data-*` attributes will still be there to be sorted on.

Comment: ... that's what i have asked for ... i do not know/i am unsure if utilizing jquery , with a `.data(key, value)`-call, really adds an attribute like `data-key="value"`, which can be accessed from all browsers with `a.getAttribute('data-key')`

Comment: Adding non-existing data-attributes via `$.data` will only be stored in `$.cache` afaik

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan so your answer could only be used, if i utilize real attributes and not `.data(key, value)`-calls. nevertheless i will upvote your answer, but not check it as my solution ...

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i've checked your answer as solution, because i could use your main-idea and rather use `.attr(key, value)` to attach my sort-value instead of `.data(key, value)`, which can be read by every browser with your code!

Comment: No. I get 3, 1, 900, -400, etc in windows chrome and mobile safari.

Comment: There's edit to the question that I made — there should be "-" instead of "<"

Comment: That edit is flawed - you don't want to return any number to `sort()`, only `1`, `0` or `-1`. Either way, the issue is because the values aren't being treated as integers. You need to use `parseInt()` on them. Fixed example: http://jsfiddle.net/b8k3ycfy/1/

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Chrome 45 on windows 8